# main function runs twice, but works normally second call in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a automation script which based on user input executes other scripts whose methods are called and fed the input as arguments.

Problem is, when the main script is first run, the user is asked for information twice.
After the second run, the script works as intended for the next runs without error.

import of function in main script

```
from spw import seaSec
```

```
#main function to call for pw resets
def menu ():
    con = ""
    
    while (con!= "no"):

        empID = input("What is the employee ID ")
        last4 = input("What are ") 
        answer = input("Which website would you like to go to ").lower()
        
        if answer == "sea":
            seaSec(empID, last4)
    
        #Will add once OmniCo script works
        #elif answer == "omni"
        #omniCo(empID, last4)
    
        con = input("Need help with anything else? (Enter y or n) ")

        if con == "n":
            quit()

menu()
```

```
def seaSec(empID, last4):
    from **** import createTicket
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    driver.get("http://wodapp/SecurityServices/Admin/FindUser.aspx")
    driver.minimize_window()

    #Input employee ID input to verify
    ID = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_sapPersonnelNumberTextBox')
    ID.send_keys(empID)
    
    #submit information 
    Sub = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_submitImageButton")
    Sub.click()


    #Hold SSN for verification, then compare to user input
    VER = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_userRepeater_editImageButton_0')
    VER.click()

    num= driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_").get_attribute('value')
    
while cont != "0":

        if (last4 == num):
            cont = 0
            break

        elif (last4 != num):
            print("Value does not match")
            return False


    firstName = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_firstNameTextBox").get_attribute('value')
    lastName = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_lastNameTextBox").get_attribute('value')

    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName

    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_homeParkDropDownList"))
    parkID = select.first_selected_option.text

    driver.back()

    choice = input("basic or xstore? ").lower()

    def spw(): 
       Reset = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_userRepeater_resetPasswordImageButton_0")
       Reset.click()
       
       print(createTicket("pwd", parkID, empID, fullName, "Sea-Port" ))
        
       driver.quit()
    
    def xpw():
        xStore = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_userRepeater_manageXStoreImageButton_0")
        xStore.click()

        choice = input("Unlock or PW? ").lower()

        if choice == "unlock":
            unlock = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_unlockImageButton")
            unlock.click()

            print(createTicket("unlock", parkID, empID, fullName, "Xstore"))

        elif choice == "pw":
            reset = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_resetPasswordImageButton")
            reset.click()

            print(createTicket("pwd", parkID, empID, fullName, "Xstore"))


    if choice == "basic":
        spw()
    elif choice == "xstore":
        xpw()
    
    driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in `spw.py` other than the `seaSec` function definition?

Comment: That's not the function that produced screen you are showing. Please show the code that produced that output, or the output produced by that code.

Comment: The code you're showing works fine if I replace `seaSec(empID, last4)` by `pass`, so I agree with other comments in that there must be something in that particular function, unless the original code is doing something different than the one you're showing.

Comment: The `menu()` function has a prompt "What is your ID?", but the screenshot has "What is the employee ID".  You have not shown us the correct code.

Comment: oh sorry its the same code, just edited the input field. I'll edit it.